# Uninitialized Constant MessagesController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a simple chat app based on [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub?view=asciicast). I'm following along fine, but when I go to localhost, I get an error "uninitialized constant MessagesController::Message". This is generally a simple fix, but I have spent over an hour looking for the fix and I cannot see it. Here is my code;

messages_controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @messages = Message.all
    end

    def create
        @message = Message.create!(params[:message])
        PrivatePub.publish_to("/messages/new", "alert('#{@message.content}');")
    end

end
```

model (message.rb)

```
class Message
end
```

index & message form (index.html.erb);

```
<h1>Hack Chat</h1>

<ul id="chat">
    <%= render @messages %>
</ul>

<%= form_for Message.new, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>

<%= subscribe_to "/messages/new" %>
```

routes.rb;

```
Hackchat::Application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'messages#index'
    resources :messages
end
```

gemfile;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do 
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'private_pub'
gem "thin", "~> 1.6.1"
```

I have checked every possible thing I could think of as to why I would be getting this error, and I really do not know why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, for using private pub, do I have to run two terminal windows, one running rails server, and the other running faye?

Comment: Did you create a model called Message? Please post the code

Comment: Yes I did. I just updated.

Comment: Like @zrl3dx pointed out, change your model name to `Message` from `Messages`

Comment: I did, and unfortunately I still got the error; NameError (uninitialized constant MessagesController::Message):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:4:in `index'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is `@Messages`, change it to `@message`.

To change it like you should use migration:

```
def change
  rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
end
```

Of   course do not create that file by hand but use rails generator:

```
rails g migration ChangeMessagesToMessage
```

That will generate new file with proper timestamp in name in `'db` dir. Then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And your app should be fine since then.

Comment: I changed it to message.rb, and I still got this error; NameError (uninitialized constant MessagesController::Message):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:4:in `index'

Comment: don't just rename it, also change the contents to `class Message`

Comment: I did, the file is message.rb and "class Message". That fixed the constant, but now I get an error; "undefined method `all' for Message:Class"

Comment: Right now the `Message` class is just a raw class... `class Message < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: That's what I thought, and I changed it. It's now class Message < ActiveRecord::Base. However, now I get an error; "SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: messages: SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" . I have sqlite3 in my gem file, but I do not need a database. I'm stuck right now.

Comment: Make sure you have a migration that creates the messages table and make sure you've run the migration.

Comment: @user1804592: sorry, I was writing from my phone and didn't write everything as I should, I forgot that you will probably just drop `s` in name instead of using migration, I'm adding appropriate info to my answer right now.