# Heroku Crashing on Rake DB:Migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have posted [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864272/uninitialized-constant-messagescontroller/20864303#20864303) [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864584/sqlite3sqlexception-no-such-table-messages-select-messages-from-messag/20864836#20864836) about a project I am working on, and I finally got it working to how I want it to.

I uploaded my stuff to heroku, and had to spend a couple hours figuring out how to get rid of all instances of sqlite3 and switch to PG. I got that fixed, but was still getting an error. Turned out to be a migration.

I ran `heroku open` and got the error page. I ran `heroku logs` and got this error;

```
2014-01-08T22:51:29.356850+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "messages" does not exist
2014-01-08T22:51:29.356850+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
```

That error I remembered was for not running your migrations. So I then ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, and then `heroku run rake db:migrate` and I got the error;

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9247
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateMessages
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:978:in `validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:876:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Originally I had 2 migration files with the same thing because I forgot about migrations. I manually went into `db/migrate` and deleted one of them. I then did

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

then I ran

```
git push heroku master
```

to try and get it on the same level, but I still have this error. Does anyone know what I could do to fix this? Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Did you get that message locally or on the heroku command?  From `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or from `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: You are doing a drop and create before migrate, right?

Comment: You've deleted the file, but git add does not remove it from the repository. git rm sounds more like what you want.

Comment: @nzifnab I got the message from the heroku command.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I just did (I forgot) and ran it locally. I ran `heroku run rake db:drop` and got FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I ran `git rm db/migrate/20140103233510_create_messages.rb` and deleted it

Comment: for what you've removed that file? once a migration added, it becomes required in the project always.

Comment: Please refer to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist/19804714#19804714 and make sure that reinitialize DB from a scratch is passed on local pc, otherwise you need to fix your migrations, and only then you shell to push into heroku.

Comment: @majioa thank you so much! That worked, and I got it live on heroku. I just have to set up another for private pub/faye to work on heroku.

Answer (score 2):

FIRST: it's my understanding that you are ok with resetting your db instance. If that's correct, keep reading Option 1:

#### Option 1:

First reset your db:
`heroku pg:reset` as noted [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset)

Then confirm that you have indeed remove your conflicting migrations. Proceed with any git push if you need.

At this point, re-migrate your db:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

#### Option 2:

Please comment below if you are not planning to reset your DB. It becomes a whole lot trickier then, and the right solution is probably more migrations or roll backs to fix your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Once a migration have been added, it becomes required all time when the project is exist. So you can only add migrations, and not remove them. If you have did a mistake in a migration rule, just add another rule that shell revert or fix your changes.

Please refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist/19804714#19804714) on how to do or redo migrations, and make sure that reinitialize DB from a scratch is passed on local PC, otherwise you need to fix your migrations, and only then you shell be able to push into heroku.